# MockElasticSearch - Can it output different results off an optional parameter just for testing?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pytest

I have a function that uses MockElasticSearch to help test 2 different functions. These 2 different functions need 2 different return values, say "A" and "B".

When I call es.search(...), the parameters I input are exactly the same, so I cannot filter by parameter to choose whether es.search() returns "A" or "B".

My question is, can I put my own optional parameter for the purposes of testing into es.search(..., my_optional_param = "First_Function") for the first function and similarly for the second function so that I can do the following in es.search?

```
es.search():
   if my_optional_param == "First_Function":
      return A
   else:
      return B
```

Would this work for the purposes of testing? Will this break prod (e.g. when the MockElasticSearch is no longer needed)?

Thank you so much!